# Separating BIN from Stripe.js

Tags: stripe-payments, maxmind, fraud-prevention

I want to use Stripe for payments, but want to be able separate the [BIN/IIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Issuer_Identification_Numbers) from the 16 digit credit card number the user enters,  before Stripe.js encrypts all the digits bar the last 4 ie. ************1457

Basically, I want to integrate MaxMind into the my Stripe powered payment page, and have MaxMind do a few checks on BIN matching before the transaction is captured by Stripe.

Stripe says this isn't supported currently, yet they do suggest using MaxMind  for identifying PrePaid cards (which is done via BIN identification).

Any ideas what the correct answer is (hello Stripe:)  and how to accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using Stripe.js, don't overthink it. ;) This is just a matter of calling your own code before (or possibly instead of) calling Stripe's. Until you call `Stripe.card.createToken`, your form data is untouched.

Do note that, like Stripe does, you'll want to do the number manipulation client-side to avoid your server falling into PCI scope. An isolated BIN/IIN is not (*currently*) considered privileged data; you can pull it out with `substring` and then send that willy-nilly anywhere you like.

At that point it's a matter of deciding how durable you want your Maxmind integration to be. If you're not overly concerned with a nefarious visitor overriding your JavaScript, you could simply do the Maxmind check inline, before calling Stripe, via their HTTP API.

Comment: This is exactly what I did to get the BIN. However, I learned over time that maxmind score isn't even near accurate. I received fraudulent orders with a score of 0.1.

Answer (score 3):

This is no longer possible with Stripe.js v3 (the previous answer was from 2013, and v3 was released some time later). This is because v3 is an iframe that is embedded on your page, and it is not possible for you to access the values in that iframe from your page.

In Stripe.js v2 this used to be possible, but actually even handling card details on the client side requires you to have an SAQ A-EP, rather than the slightly simpler SAQ A. Read more about it here: https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance

For the purposes of identifying prepaid cards, the Stripe API will tell you [the card type](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-card-funding) in the API. If you really need the BIN, you can ask Stripe Support about enabling that for you in the response in the API.